# First course: Do I need to download bootstrap? And where do I download it?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm completeing the first course "First landing page" and I can't figure out how or if I need to download bootstrap. Is there some link in the tutorial?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: go to bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/download/

Answer (score 0):

You probably do. I am unfamiliar with that course. When I use bootstrap with just html I have to download it. This is a good place to start:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/download/

They have some snippets on using it and if you look around getbootstrap.com there is plenty of help in the form of Getting Started, Examples and Documentation sections

Answer (score 0):

Its on you if you want to download it you can download it or you can simply include the online source file link into your file.

You can include link like this in your `html` file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Or you can download the file from [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/download/)